# Calling the method - new to this

Tags: java

I am writing a program to collate two strings of text.  For example, "google" and "chrome" becomes "gcohorgmlee" (you can assume that the letters are equal length).

```
public class Collate {

    String result;
    String a;
    String b;

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Enter 1st word: ");
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in1.next();
        System.out.printf("Enter second word: ");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        b = in2.next();

    }

    public String collate(String a, String b) {
        String accumulator;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;


        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            result += a.charAt(i);
            result += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return (result);
    }
}
```

I am stuck however on how to call `collate()`. I am very new to Java and hardly know anything, so some pointers and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `System.out.println(collate(a,b));`?

Comment: @KarthikT that won't work never.

Comment: Please remember to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/206447) you found most helpful to each of your questions (and also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) useful answers (and questions), especially answers to your own questions, if you don't do so already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer be to simple say, use `collate(a, b)` and either assign the value back to a variable or print it to the screen...

The longer answer ends the same, but starts by pointing out the your program won't actually run at the moment...

`public void main(String[] args){` is not a valid entry point for your program.  Instead, it should be `public static void main(String[] args){`

Now, if you do this, you will end up with a number of compiler errors stating the some non-static part of your application can not be accessed from a static context...

The simplest solution would be to provide a `constructor` to the `Collate` class which can be called from `main`...

```
public class Collate{
    String result;
    String a;
    String b;

    public void main(String[] args){
        new Collate();
    }

    public Collate() {
        System.out.printf("Enter 1st word: "); 
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in1.next();
        System.out.printf("Enter second word: ");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        b = in2.next();
        String collation = collate(a, b);
        System.out.println(collation);
    }

    public String collate(String a, String b){
        String accumulator;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;


        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            result += a.charAt(i);
            result += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return (result);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

I seem to have create a nice rampage over responsibility.  While it can argue that the classes responsibility is to ask the user what they want to do and do, it is also arguable that the class should be self contained it's task, for example...

```
public class Collate{
    String result;
    String a;
    String b;

    public void main(String[] args){
        System.out.printf("Enter 1st word: "); 
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in1.next();
        System.out.printf("Enter second word: ");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        b = in2.next();
        Collate collate = new Collate();
        String collation = collate.collate(a, b);
        System.out.println(collation);
        new Collate();
    }

    public String collate(String a, String b){
        String accumulator;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;


        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            result += a.charAt(i);
            result += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return (result);
    }
}
```

Because there is a significant lack of context, coming to a concrete solution is impossible...

Comment: Asking for user input in a constructor? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Probably, but why not?

Comment: Why not? Reusability, separate what is `view` and `logic` , be responsible of one thing. If tomorrow i want to use this class in a swing application i think i wont want console input.

Comment: [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)?

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said and it works accept the result has 'null' in it. for example: 
1st word - google
2nd word - chrome
result - nullgcohorgolmee

Comment: @nachokk Normally I wouldn't disagree, but simply smacking `static` in front of everything is also not a suitable solution.  Following on basic needs at the moment and addressing two possible solutions to the same problem...

Comment: Im agree with your solution , the only think im disagree is about your automatic object behaviour in constructor. i'd put that code in main method instead of in Collate constructor

Comment: @Dukeling Normally I wouldn't argue, but it's nice to get other peoples points of view on the subject.  Without context, it's difficult to know exactly what the best approach might be.  The class might be responsible for obtain the details from the user and performing actions on them, that might be it's purpose.  Equally, as nachokk has pointed it, the responsibility for the class might be just to perform the operations on the values.  Both are equally valid and correct...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually I think using `static` is indeed the correct behaviour for this problem (and the `String` class variables should be removed), since `collate` takes 2 parameters and returns something, it's not dependent on an internal state.

Comment: @Dukeling We're lacking context to make those decisions in the long wrong.  I don't ever believe `static` is a good choice without first knowing the overall context.  Sure, if it's a utility method, you are right.  But there is no context to make that decision.  The OP may need to make further operations internally to the state of the class, they might not.  Using `static` isn't wrong, this is just another point of view and means to accomplish the goal, that's all

Comment: @nachokk Just so we're clear, I don't disagree with you either and I appreciate you taking the time to provide feedback.  It's always good to get other peoples ideas and point's of view.

Comment: :D i learn a lot with you in swing :D only one thing you have `new Collate()` at the end of constructor

Answer (score 2):

Not to take anything away from the other answers, here's my take.

Here's what I changed:

- Removed the class variables. They don't really mean much outside of the `collate` call.
- Removed `in2`. You should only really have 1 `Scanner`.
- Removed `accumulator`. It wasn't used.
- Changed `main` to `static`, otherwise it's not seen as an entry point by Java.
- Changed `collate` to `static`, since it's no longer dependent on any class instance variables, and it being `static` allows `main` to directly call it.
- Initialized `result` to an empty string.

Code:

```
public class Collate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter 1st word: ");
        String a = in1.next();
        System.out.printf("Enter second word: ");
        String b = in1.next();
        System.out.println(collate(a,b));
    }

    public static String collate(String a, String b) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            result += a.charAt(i);
            result += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

A more efficient option would be using `StringBuilder`:
(although this is unlikely to be necessary for code written outside of a production environment, and even most production code as well)

```
public static String collate(String a, String b) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        result.append(a.charAt(i));
        result.append(b.charAt(i));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: @nachokk Added code for StringBuilder. As long as I'm using an IDE that warns me about using static members of variables, I can't really justify a private constructor for a class with all-static members.

Comment: If you have all things static then private constructor have a lot of sense, cause why you let an user create an instance of your class if you have all static..

Comment: @nachokk Fair point, but personally I'd prefer one less method (even if empty) and risk it.

Comment: @nachokk I'd prefer not having the private constructor and risking someone creating an instance of my class.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, `collate` is using `String` variables that belong to a particular instance of the `Collate` class, but it really doesn't need to; all of the information that it needs to do its job is getting passed in as parameters. Since the instance variables (fields) `Collate.a` and `Collate.b` aren't doing anything useful, you can eliminate them, and the `result` variable is also only useful in within the `collate` method, so you should declare it there instead (this is what that `accumulator` is for, so use that variable; you need to set it to the empty string `""` to start out). (In fact, your current version will fail if you call `collate` multiple times, because it will just add characters to the end of the previous result.)

You can make `collate` `static`, which means that it doesn't need information that belongs to any particular `Collate`, and call it directly from `main`:

```
public static String collate(String a, String b) {
    String accumulator = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        accumulator += a.charAt(i);
        accumulator += b.charAt(i);
    }
    return accumulator;
}

// in main
System.out.println(collate(a,b));
```

Comment: This is perfectly clear to an experienced Java programmer, however, I feel the (word-based) explanation may be a bit difficult for new programmers to follow.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try to re-explain.

Comment: @nachokk Thanks for the heads-up; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So...a couple of issues with this code.

Your member variables `a` and `b` are not declared `static`; hence, they cannot be referenced from `main` (which should also be `static`).

Use a local variable instead of `a` or `b` (so you don't get the names mixed up), and have them persist in `main`.  You can also get rid of the member variables outright.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String firstWord;  // takes the place of a
    String secondWord; // takes the place of b
    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

Now, to call the method on your class, you need [to instantiate a new instance of `Collate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

```
Collate col = new Collate();
```

To call the method, you use the instance, and call `collate()` with the arguments that represent what you want to permutate.  I'll leave the filling in of the blanks as an exercise to the reader.

```
System.out.println(col.<insert_method_here>(_which_was_a?, _which_was_b?));
```

Lastly, the variable `accumulator` exists in the scope of `collate`, but `result` does not.  Choose `accumulator` to append to.  Get rid of your assignments to your member variables as well.

Answer (score -1):

All in all, here is what you need

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Collate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in1 = null;
        Scanner in2 = null;
        try {
            System.out.printf("Enter 1st word: ");
            in1 = new Scanner(System.in);

            String a = in1.next();

            System.out.printf("Enter second word: ");
            in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String b = in2.next();

            System.out.println(new Collate().collate(a, b));
        } finally {
            in1.close();
            in2.close();
        }

    }

    public String collate(String a, String b) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length(), b.length()); i++) {
            result += a.charAt(i);
            result += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return (result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain _why_.

Comment: Making `a` and `b` static fields will prevent you from calling the function from 2 threads at the same time (i.e. it's not reentrant). There's no real need to have two additional variables that only point to the same function parameters.